# Adding .exe Reference in WCF Dynamically

Tags: wcf, visual-studio, dll, com, exe

Let's say I have a WCF web service which uses some 3rd party `.exe` file for some calculations.

Basically, when I am developing the service in Visual Studio, I would go to add reference and select that exe and build it and copy the dll's to prod environment.

But the 3rd party component which I am using needs to be installed before using it. So I would install in some folder on prod. But now since my code is already compiled, I cannot add reference to this exe.

Is there a way to add reference to an exe dynamically?

If not, do I have the only option of installing Visual Studio on Prod server, add reference and compile again?

Thank you,

Comment: You shouldn't need to install VS on a production box (and most companies security team would have a cow - or several - if you asked permission).  I would try ensuring that the .exe is installed in the same location on every machine and set the program to reference that location.

Comment: Yes, but how will you add refernce form code?

Comment: How are you using it now?  Since it's an exe, my first guess would be you're calling it somehow.

Comment: Its still in development so, I added refernce in Visual studio, it will create one Interop.dll whcih holds info about exe